# (probably very simple) initWithString doesn't seem to work

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

The objc tutorial I'm following uses the following initialization:

```
NSString* p = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"something"];
```

However, the same tutorial stated in a previous chapter that these type of constructs can be broken into pieces like:

```
NSString* p = [NSString alloc];
[p initWithString: @"something"];
```

However, if I try to display the value of *p* using NSLog, an exception occures:

```
main: Uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException, reason: attempt to use uninitialised string
```

This is probably an easy one but I can't seem to find the answer to this.

Comment: At what point are you trying to display `p`?

Comment: after initWithString, of course:)

Comment: NSString *p = @"something"; is even easier. I believe LLVM now even throws a warning at you when using stringWithString: with a literal string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set your variable to the return value of init:

```
NSString* p = [NSString alloc];
p = [p initWithString: @"something"];
```

Comment: Yes, that did it:) Thanks! That wasn't very intuitive for me, as I expected something called "init" to actually initialize:)

Answer (score 2):

This is from [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s manual, about the init method:

> In some cases, an init method might return a substitute object. You must therefore always use the object returned by init, and not the one returned by alloc or allocWithZone:, in subsequent code.